# Consistant parse float values on uneven data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of float numbers, representing currency, and I need to turn them into integers, for precision.

The task is to turn float numbers into integers, likes:

- 0.95 => 95
- 1 => 100
- 1,465.01 => 146501

The problem is:

1. I don't have access to change the input csv files
2. The numbers came in a variety of ways (1.00, 1.0, 1, .95, 0.95, etc)

How can, **safely**, I turn these numbers into integers?

Some examples of my problem:

- `('16.81'.to_f * 100).to_i` => 1680
- `('16.81'.to_f * 100_00).to_i / 100` => 1681
- `('342.28'.to_f * 100).to_i` => 34228
- `('342.28'.to_f * 100_00).to_i / 100` => 34227

__ EDIT __

By the way, I'm using `ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin19]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point numbers can't necessarily represent all decimal numbers. This is explained in [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/421705). As such, when dealing with floats, you are always a bit uncertain and usually need to use rounding to get a desired number.

From your examples, `('16.81'.to_f * 100)` results in `1680.9999999999998`. Getting the integer value from that cuts off the fractional part, resulting in `1680`. By using `round` instead, you can get the desired integer (which also solves the issue of partial cents). When relying on this, please [note the details](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html#method-i-round) of how Ruby rounds exactly, specifically the optional `half` argument).

Instead of relying on Floats however, a better idea is to use BigDecimal numbers instead which allow arbitrary precision floating point numbers.

```
require 'bigdecimal'

(BigDecimal('16.81') * 100).round
# => 1681

(BigDecimal('.95') * 100).round
# => 95

number = '1,465.01'
# remove any "additional" characters
normalized = number.gsub(/[^-+0-9.]/, '')
(BigDecimal(normalized) * 100).round
# => 146501
```

In the last example, I have shown how you might cleanup your "human-readable" numbers for consistent parsing. Depending on your source data, you might need to perform additional changes (e.g. if you might have values such as `'1.465,01'` as is common in e.g. some European countries).

Answer (score 1):

Use Bigdecimal for `float` numbers and append `.to_i` to convert it in `integer`

```
require 'bigdecimal'
(BigDecimal('16.81') * 100).to_i  # 1681
(BigDecimal('342.28') * 100).to_i # 34228
```

For more details you can refer https://corainchicago.github.io/blog/why-does-ruby-add-numbers-wrong/

Comment: 100_00 is 10,000. Really just need `('16.81'.to_f * 100)`

Comment: do you mind running the examples I gave? you will see that if it works with `16.81` it will not work with `342.28`

Comment: @RipTheJacker: 100_00 is 10,000, correct, this is just an example, whatever operations u do, at the end , need to add .to_i